# Is this some kind of favicon link standard?

Tags: curl, httpwebrequest, html-parsing, favicon

context: im writing a favicon parser: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-favicons/trunk/includes/class-http.php and http://wp.leau.co/2011/03/18/handling-redirects-for-wp-favicons-with-redirects-set-to-0-with-wordpress-wp_remote_get/

I saw : http://www.foxfilm.nl/favicon.ico in the tests, I wanted to conclude that this is an error by the site developer but im not 100% sure. Is this some kind of standard I dont know of?

Comment: Heh, that _looks_ like someone didn't understand how to use `ln(1)` command -- but firefox seems to load the favicon.ico just fine. Good question.

Comment: so you are saying it IS a standard i dont know hmmmm have to look it up...

Comment: Wow, [there's so much more to favicon.ico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) than I ever expected. Neat. Thanks. :)

Comment: i include that link in the docs but I cant find reference to this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not any sort of standard. The favicon shows up when going to http://www.foxfilm.nl/ because the page contains a meta tag directing the browser to a non-default location for the file:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/common/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: ok. no standard it is. probably a mistake by the owner. dropped. the reason i landed there was because my testset did domain/fdsfdsf.html which gave a 404 which contain HTML. I then try to parse the 404 page for that rel tag, if not then try /favicon.ico in the root but its a good idea to add in between a check for checking the root domain PAGE before the /favicon.ico in the root. tnx.